# Will getting a vaccine have any additional effect on your immune system if you already got covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

Supposedly people who got covid-19 get immunity after it. According to this article,

[More SARS-COV-2 reinfections reported but still a rare event](https://www.the-scientist.com/news-opinion/more-sars-cov-2-reinfections-reported-but-still-a-rare-event-68089) citing several studies,

> Bertollini and his colleagues conclude in their report that “the risk
> for documented reinfection was very rare at about 1-2 reinfections per
> 10,000 infected persons.” The researchers further note that the
> “findings suggest that most infected persons do develop immunity
> against reinfection that lasts for at least [a] few months, and that
> reinfections (if they occur) are well tolerated and no more
> symptomatic than primary infections

Are there any reasons for people to get vaccinated?

Will getting a vaccine have any additional effect on your immune system if you already got covid-19?

Comment: You sure about an infection providing immunity? Numerous examples exist of people being infected with Covid more than once. Your question could use a bit more research.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm not 100% sure, but since governments here have made laws that you can circulate freely if you already got covid because "you already have immunity", some data has to back it up. The largest reinfection estimate I've seen mentioned in one research is 1 in 400 people, in México if I recall correctly, which is one of the countries with the largest amount of cases.  Directly, until a couple of months ago, there were around a dozen of cases confirmed worldwide, which were deemed as rare cases

Comment: If you provided sources for those numbers in the question, you'd have a good question.

Comment: @CareyGregory any better now?

Comment: @CareyGregory have these "numerous examples" been verified to not be related to false-positive tests or mutated strands? People also "reinfect" with the flu and common cold regularly, to which Sars-Cov-2 is related, which to my understanding is because of mutation.

Comment: @Xerus I don't know, maybe a good question for the OP.

Comment: @xerus according to the answer to this question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90718/how-many-times-has-sars-cov-2-mutated . sars-cov-2 mutates almost daily and there are hundreds of mutations already , so I dont really know which mutations makes a virus worthy of being classified as a new strain.

Comment: It would seem some researchs / studies dont even take into account different strains and treat the virus as a single thing

Answer (score 3):

I've found an answer to this,

> If I have already had COVID-19 and recovered, do I still need to get
> vaccinated with a COVID-19 vaccine?
>
> Yes. Due to the severe health risks associated with COVID-19 and the
> fact that re-infection with COVID-19 is possible, vaccine should be
> offered to you regardless of whether you already had COVID-19
> infection. CDC is providing recommendations to federal, state, and
> local governments about who should be vaccinated first.
>
> At this time, experts do not know how long someone is protected from
> getting sick again after recovering from COVID-19. The immunity
> someone gains from having an infection, called natural immunity,
> varies from person to person. Some early evidence suggests natural
> immunity may not last very long.
>
> We won’t know how long immunity produced by vaccination lasts until we
> have more data on how well the vaccines work.
>
> Both natural immunity and vaccine-induced immunity are important
> aspects of COVID-19 that experts are trying to learn more about, and
> CDC will keep the public informed as new evidence becomes available.

[Facts about COVID-19 Vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/facts.html#:%7E:text=It%20typically%20takes%20a%20few,vaccination%20and%20still%20get%20sick.)